# Get Info From Script Tag (WebScrape)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
#Python Code
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

url ='https://www. SomeData .com'
req = urllib3.PoolManager()
res = req.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.data, 'html.parser')
res = soup.find_all('script')
print(res)
```

Then I Got something like this:

```
Results below:
[
  <script>
        AAA.trackData.taxonomy = {
              a:"a",
              b:"b",
              c:"c2,
              ...} ;
</script>
</script>, <script async="" src="https://someData.com/js/detail.0a6eca28.js"></script>
]
```

How can i convert this to a json format to treat well data inside  tag.

Comment: Whats your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this helps.

```
script = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('AAA\.trackData\.taxonomy'))
json_text = re.search(r'^\s*AAA\.trackData\.taxonomy\s*=\s*({.*?})\s*;\s*$',
                      script.string, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE).group(1)
data = json.loads(json_text)
```