# String to Json Python

Tags: python, json

```
Print(Json_text)
'{\n                    \n                        acorn: "",\n                        acorn_type: "",\n                        area_name: "Glasgow",\n                        beds_max: 2,\n                        beds_min: 2,\n }
```

I tried to solve it doing:

```
json_text = re.sub(r'\n', '',json_text)
json_text = re.sub(r' ', '',json_text)
```

then the results:

```
print(json_text)
'{acorn:"",acorn_type:"",area_name:"Glasgow",beds_max:2,beds_min:2,branch_id:"32896"}
```

then I tried to convert to Json Format:

```
json_text= json.dumps(json_text)
json_text = json.loads(json_text)
```

But the final value is an string.

```
json_text['area_name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

i think is because the Key values don't have quotations ("")

Comment: Put quotes around the keys (ie “acorn” and not acorn

Comment: It's not valid JSON, the string keys are unquoted by your approach

Comment: how did you get `Json_text` ? It is not correct JSON. If you generate this JSON  then change method - use module `json` for this.

Comment: that's not a valid json, of course you couldnt parse that

Comment: you can try module [dirtyjson](https://github.com/codecobblers/dirtyjson) - it can handle some problems in wrong JSON.

Comment: here is the previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232015/get-info-from-script-tag-webscrap?noredirect=1#comment100967012_57232015

Comment: Can you specify what you are trying to achieve? Your code seems inconsistent in some ways, e.g. 1) `json.dumps` takes a Python object (eg dictionary) as input and turns it into a string, but you give it a string; 2) it's not clear to me why you would manuipulate your string before writing to JSON, etc. It would be good to know 1. Where is your input from? 2. Why are you converting to JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do replacements to make it json parse-able:

```
In [120]: text = '{\n                    \n                        acorn: "",\n                        acorn_type: "",\n                        area_name: "Glasgow",\n                        beds_max: 2,\
     ...: n                        beds_min: 2,\n }'                                                                                                                                                        

In [121]: json.loads(re.sub(r'\b([^:",]+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', re.sub(r'\s*|,\s*(?=\}$)', '', text)))                                                                                                            
Out[121]: 
{'acorn': '',
 'acorn_type': '',
 'area_name': 'Glasgow',
 'beds_max': 2,
 'beds_min': 2}
```

---

At first, we need to drop all whitespaces and the trailing `,`:

```
In [122]: re.sub(r'\s*|,\s*(?=\}$)', '', text)                                                                                                                                                              
Out[122]: '{acorn:"",acorn_type:"",area_name:"Glasgow",beds_max:2,beds_min:2}'
```

Now, on the returned string, we need to add double quotes to the keys:

```
In [123]: re.sub(r'\b([^:",]+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', re.sub(r'\s*|,\s*(?=\}$)', '', text))                                                                                                                        
Out[123]: '{"acorn":"","acorn_type":"","area_name":"Glasgow","beds_max":2,"beds_min":2}'
```

Now, `json.loads` would do:

```
In [124]: json.loads(re.sub(r'\b([^:",]+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', re.sub(r'\s*|,\s*(?=\}$)', '', text)))                                                                                                            
Out[124]: 
{'acorn': '',
 'acorn_type': '',
 'area_name': 'Glasgow',
 'beds_max': 2,
 'beds_min': 2}
```

---

Using names:

```
In [125]: text                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[125]: '{\n                    \n                        acorn: "",\n                        acorn_type: "",\n                        area_name: "Glasgow",\n                        beds_max: 2,\n                        beds_min: 2,\n }'

In [126]: text_wo_whitespaces = re.sub(r'\s*|,\s*(?=\}$)', '', text)                                                                                                                                        

In [127]: text_quoted = re.sub(r'\b([^:",]+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', text_wo_whitespaces)                                                                                                                           

In [128]: json.loads(text_quoted)                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[128]: 
{'acorn': '',
 'acorn_type': '',
 'area_name': 'Glasgow',
 'beds_max': 2,
 'beds_min': 2}
```